# Cannot hit the 'OK' button - E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock - Software center probable issue

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, software-center

I use Ubuntu 16.04.
Since few days when I try to install an application I receive the following error message below.

For example, today the following :

```
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Provides the following error message :

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock
>   (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

I also tried to resolve the issue as advised [here](https://itsfoss.com/could-not-get-lock-error/), using the followings commands :

```
$sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$sudo lsof /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Then :

```
$sudo kill -9 <process_id>
```

Then the commands below :

```
$sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
$sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then the command :

```
$sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

However, when enter again the command below I have a frame asking to hit "OK" while it's not possible (as you can see in the file attached):

```
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

The issue may come from Software Center/Ubuntu Software since it doesn't launch.[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try the spacebar?

Comment: Since OK is marked, pressing <Enter> should do the trick.
If more choices where available, you could navigate between then with tab-key.

Comment: I tried <Enter> but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

From `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ttf-mscorefonts-installer.postinst` you can find the value to pre-accept the EULA

```
# if the license was not accepted, ensure the fonts are removed
# and add README with helpful information
 FONTDIR=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts
 mkdir -p $FONTDIR
 license=mscorefonts-eula
 db_get msttcorefonts/accepted-$license
 if [ "$RET" != "true" ]; then
     echo "user did not accept the $license license" >&2
    rm -f $FONTDIR/*.ttf
    cat > $FONTDIR/README <<EOF 
License refused.
```

So we can use the [debconf-set-selections](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/debconf-set-selections.1.html) utility:

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true
| sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then install:

```
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Comment: I still recurrently having the error message above. Maybe I should re-install linux.

Comment: `ps aux | grep [a]pt` ?

Comment: I've re-installed Ubuntu. I believe I presently face hackers attacks.